# Feynman Kac solution discontinuity at 0

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

In most exposition of the Feynman Kac formula
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) +  \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -V(x,t) u(x,t) = 0$$  the condition of the derivative at 0 is left pretty fuzzy. In the original Kac paper, it is said that $u'(0-)-u'(0+)=2$ which I can wrap my head around if we rewrite the equation as a Sturm Liouville operator and look for the Green function.

Yet others use of the formula state that the derivative should be continuous at 0, for example in the Brownian motion textbook of Karatzas and Shreve : $u'(0+)=u'(0-)$

So which one is it : jump discontinuity the sizw of 1/p(x) for the Sturm Liouville operator, or continuity of the derivatice at 0 ?

Thanks.